# UML, Class identification and relationship

Tags: uml

Beginer in UML, I have the followings rules for an Aikido club management:

R1: Every member should participate to the training practices.

R2: The trainees can come from other clubs in the same city or country as well as abroad.

I identify 2 classes:

[image]

To take into account the second rule:

- Member (1) and Trainee (0..1)
- Trainee(1.. *) and Training (1.. *)

Is there a correct way in what I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this is ok. But the `m-n` relation between `Member` and `Training` should better be modeled as association class:

[image]

In this case you are able to add individual properties of members per training. When implementing this you will likely feel the need to introduce some glue (like a table in a database) between both.

I have also added a `Club` class assuming that a member is bound to just a single club. If you want to model multi-club relations you would probably again use an association class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Do you suggest me to cancel the Trainee Class?

Comment: The `MemberTaining` will represent the trainee. It shows in which training a member took part.

Comment: Oky. What about canceling Club Class and just have a property "club" in Member Class? Sorry for my stupid questions.

Comment: You can simply put a String property in `Member` to hold the club name. Of course this will never result in a unique club name. One will spell Dojo. Another one DoYo. Do Yo understand ;-) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram is a beginning. The [diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32821501/170781) as proposed by [Thomas Killian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/thomas-kilian) is more complete. However, in both of these diagrams there is no notion of constraints or rules. It is simply not what class diagrams are used for. What you can express (with your diagram) is that one or more members can participate in a training and that a training is frequented by at least one member.

To express that every member must participate in training courses, you could need to express that, for all the instances of your class diagram, all members are covered with at least one association towards training. To do so you will need to formulate constraints, possibly using [OCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Constraint_Language), the Object Constraint Language designed to supplement UML and address the specific shortcomings you are facing now.

Comment: Thanks @Eric. Could you show me an example of OCL in this case? And some possible links (tuto) to master it.

Comment: A tutorial can be found here: http://www.slideshare.net/jcabot/ocl-tutorial  Unfortunately my own experience with OCL is a bit dated and I would have trouble conjuring an example at this particular moment. If, after the tutorial, you still need help, get back to me and I'll see what I can do.